# How to pass a Javascript parameter through Onclick function when there is no id is defined

Tags: javascript

I want to pass which li is clicked. The clicked li number i have to pass through onclick function. There is no id is defined to any li.

Example is second li is clicked, i want to pass onclick="imageDisplayClick(2) but i am not able to get the count.

```html
<div id="slider_text">
        
       <ul onclick="imageDisplayClick()">
            
            <li><h1 style="color:orange;">SPORTS & FITNESS</h1></li>
            
            <li><h1>ACCU - CHEK Strips</h1></li>
    
            <li><h1>NATURE'S BOUNTY</h1></li>
                        
            <li><h1>Beauty Care</h1></li>
    
        </ul>
    
      </div>
```

Please help me to solve this issue

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: <div id="slider_text">

   <ul onclick="imageDisplayClick()">

        <li><h1 style="color:orange;">SPORTS & FITNESS</h1></li>

        <li><h1>ACCU - CHEK Strips</h1></li>

        <li><h1>NATURE'S BOUNTY</h1></li>

        <li><h1>Beauty Care</h1></li>

    </ul>

  </div>

Answer (score 4):

For starters, I would not recommend using the `onclick` attribute, but rather making use of [**Unobtrusive JavaScript**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript) and separating it out to a function.

After separating out the logic, it's only a small extra step to loop over the elements, which can be acquired with **[`.querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)**.

From here you now have a click handler on each individual `<li>` element that can reference the element in question with the **[`this` keyword](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)**. Because you have access to the element directly, you shouldn't actually *need* to pass through the relevant offset into the function in question.

```js
var points = document.querySelectorAll('#slider_text > ul > li');

for (var i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
  points[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
    console.log(this.innerHTML);
  })
}
```

```html
<div id="slider_text">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <h1 style="color:orange;">SPORTS & FITNESS</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>ACCU - CHEK Strips</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>NATURE'S BOUNTY</h1>
    </li>
    <li>
      <h1>Beauty Care</h1>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score 2):

Use `this`, it will pass a reference to the DOM element itself.

```
<ul onclick="imageDisplayClick(this)">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener as it makes everything lie in your javascript file and prevents from having js fragments scattered in your html.

You can then use the event parameter to find out in detail what was clicked:

Test it here https://jsfiddle.net/jteLw8qa/

HTML:

```
<div id="slider_text">
  <ul id="selection">
    <!-- data-XXX can be accessed in javascript with element.dataset.XXX AS A STRING -->
    <li data-yourdata="42"><h1 style="color:orange;">SPORTS & FITNESS</h1></li>
    <li data-yourdata="elephant"><h1>ACCU - CHEK Strips</h1></li>
    <li data-yourdata="pink"><h1>NATURE'S BOUNTY</h1></li>
    <li data-yourdata="stackoverflow"><h1>Beauty Care</h1></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function imageDisplayClick(event)
{
    // find the clicked li element
  var target = event.target;
  // find first parent li or ul
  while(target.tagName != 'LI' && target.tagName != 'UL')
      target = target.parentNode;// because you have <h1> in your <li>
  // if li is a parent the user clicked on it, else he clicked on the side but still on the ul
  if(target.tagName == 'LI')
    alert('clicked li with data-yourdata=' + target.dataset.yourdata);
}

// have the click event being listened on our ul#selection element
document.getElementById('selection').addEventListener('click', imageDisplayClick);
```

Comment: You can eliminate the loop with `const target = event.target.closest('#selection > li');`. `target` will then point to either the `<li>` directly inside `#selection` containing the element that was clicked, or `null` if no such element exists.

Answer (score 0):

On top of the other answers provided, an [event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent) argument is also passed to the click handler, which should provide you with information on what specific thing was clicked on.

In your case, you could do something like this:

```js
imageDisplayClick = function(event){
 var target = event.target.tagName=="H1"?event.target.parentNode:event.target;
 console.log(target);
}
```

```html
<div id="slider_text">
        
       <ul onclick="imageDisplayClick(event)">
            
            <li><h1 style="color:orange;">SPORTS & FITNESS</h1></li>
            
            <li><h1>ACCU - CHEK Strips</h1></li>
    
            <li><h1>NATURE'S BOUNTY</h1></li>
                        
            <li><h1>Beauty Care</h1></li>
    
        </ul>
    
      </div>
```